# Горизонтальное меню уезжает вверх

Tags: webkit, шаблоны-проектирования, кросс-компиляция, css, google-chrome

CSS! Проблема в с webkit, горизонтальное меню фактически уезжает вверх так, чтобы его не было видно?

Но это происходит почему-то именно в браузерах webkit (safari,chrome), хотя в opera, IE и Firefox еще куда- ни шло, почему это происходит и как это лечить никто не подскажет?
п.с. меню резиновое, и таким должно остаться. Вот пример.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<title>Crossbrowsing Menu</title>
<style>
/* MENU */
 div.bmenu { position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 1; width: 100%; height: 6%; background: #c2c2c2; }
 div.bmenu a { position: relative; display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap; width: 20%; float: left; margin: -6.5% 0 0 0; outline: none;}
 div.bmenu img { height: 100%; width: 100%; }
 div.bmenu a:hover { margin: -5% 0 0 0; z-index: 2; }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="bmenu">
    <a class='mlink' href="#"><img alt='' name="test" border=0 src='menu/test.png'></a></li>
    <a class='mlink' href="#"><img alt='' name="test" border=0 src='menu/test.png'></a></li>
    <a class='mlink' href="#"><img alt='' name="test" border=0 src='menu/test.png'></a></li>
    <a class='mlink' href="#"><img alt='' name="test" border=0 src='menu/test.png'></a></li>
    <a class='mlink' href="#"><img alt='' name="test" border=0 src='menu/test.png'></a></li>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: у меня пашет, проверял в мозиле и в хроме.
прикрепите скрин, и укажите стрелочками что не катит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`margin: -X% 0 0 0;` зачем вставляли? Это скорее относится к background-position, чем к самому элементу.